# Gradle global exclude

Tags: gradle

How can I exclude:

```
com.sun.xml.bind:*:*
```

from all projects, all configurations, regardless of version?

I need to replace them with:

```
'org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-xjc:2.2.11'
'org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.2.11'
...
```

in accordance with:

https://github.com/jacobono/gradle-jaxb-plugin/issues/15

....hmmm... Is there a way to replace them in one step?

Comment: I've figured this out but I'll let someone answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to the [Gradle User Guide on Dependency Management](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html) explains, you can exclude all versions of a given dependency from all configurations:

```
configurations.all {
    exclude group: 'com.sun.xml.bind'
}
```

Then just add the glassfish dependencies (may need compile instead of runtime configuration)

```
dependencies {
    runtime 'org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-xjc:2.2.11'
    runtime 'org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.2.11'
}
```

Alternatively, you could try [dependency substitution](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:blacklisting_version), but that might be hairy.